# Expand or collapse label text with the show more or show less link

Tags: ios, swift

In an IOS app I have a label into a scroll view with the properties I describe below

```
          self.detailMainLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
          self.detailMainLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
          self.detailMainLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

And with the height constraint:

```
          Relation = Greater than or equal
```

When I run the app the label automatically auto-expand depending the text.
But I would like to know what can I do to implement the "show more" or "show less" link at the end of the text label to expand or colapse the height.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first you have to set the number of line to 1 or two which you want for show more button.
like

```
self.detailMainLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
self.detailMainLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
self.detailMainLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

then on show more button click set

```
self.detailMainLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
self.detailMainLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

and again on show less button click set the number of line to 2.
if you used one button for both show less and show more than also maintain one boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

```
#import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"

IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel * lblname;


// Expand Button Press
- (IBAction)btnforexpande:(id)sender
{
    if (expande == 1 ){

        NSString *strText = @“STRING”;
        NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strText attributes:
                                         @{
                                           (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
                                           NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13],
                                           }];
        lblname.text = attString;
        lblname.numberOfLines = 1;
        lblname.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        NSAttributedString *showMore = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..+more"] attributes:
                                        @{
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
                                          NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:233.0f/255.0f green:233.0f/255.0f blue:233.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                                          NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13],
                                          }];

        [lblname setAttributedTruncationToken:showMore];
        [lblname sizeToFit];

    }
    else{
        // Expand
        lblname.numberOfLines = 0;
        lblname.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        CGSize sizeTitle1 = [lblcc.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lblcc.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size;
        _lblccHight.constant = sizeTitle1.height;

    }
}
```